# How does android populate stylable members of a View when not all are supplied in custom style

Tags: android

I have a basic question about styles/theme application to actual objects.

Firstly from android documentation [Link here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

> A theme is a style applied to an entire Activity or application,
>   rather than an individual View (as in the example above). When a style
>   is applied as a theme, every View in the Activity or application will
>   apply each style property that it supports.

and from the same article

> However, if you apply a style to a View that does not support all of
>   the style properties, the View will apply only those properties that
>   are supported and simply ignore the others.

So say I use a native theme of a platform in the android manifest file in the application element.

`android:Theme.Holo.Light`

So per documents each and every view in all activities/application will be applied style properties from the theme above.

Say I have only one custom style in the entire application and I used it on a button.

```
 <style name="RedColor">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    </style>


<Button
    style="@style/RedColor"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

So all views in the application will be applied main style/theme `android:Theme.Holo.Light`

But one view (Button) gets applied my custom style called RedColor.
In RedColor style I did not specify any other properties for button and I also did not intentionally inherit the style from any other.

The document says the View will apply only those properties that
are supported and simply ignore the others.

The Question is when this particular view (Button) becomes an actual object and ofcourse the Button has more than textColor as its members how does android populate the remaining properties of this Button or View ?

Comment: Remaining properties like?

Answer (score 0):

Basically if I am not wrong,

As per your question at first the **Button** will be applied the default theme of the activity. After that when the **Button** is inflated to display inside the **Activity**, it will see for the button properties and apply to that button which are applicable to **Button**.

Comment: are u suggesting two styles are applied ? I doubt that, do you have reference to support it ?

Comment: @Ahmed But, its not written that the Button only will be applied the custom style setup by us.

Comment: Well, that's why I have posted the question there is too much confusion I think and I want convincing information not just guesses

Comment: @Ahmed basically, all the views, inside the activity will be of the type which provided by `Theme`, And here as per the example, the textColor only will be override and set from style. Don't be confuse style and themes are different things.